# Passing selected value of a listbox to another listbox in google-apps-script

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script

I am building a google apps UI and I am having trouble determining the value of an item in one listbox from the call back event in a separate listbox. I tried passing hidden events but this did not work out. How do I pass the selected grade to _clickCourse

This is a rough description of the code in english:

1) Populate the first listbox with all available unique grades
2) Attach a function to be triggered when the content of the grade listbox changes
3) In the function created in 2, I know the selected grade via the even, use that info to filter on the correct courses, populate the course listbox with the valid courses.
4) Attach a callback function to the courses listbox
5) Inside this function, filter on the selected grade + selected course to determine the valid semesters.

... The issue is that the last Function knows the selected course via the event that google UI passed to it, but it does not know the selected grade.

```
Sample Data:

Grade    Semester     Course                 Unit
1          1        Chemistry101         Chemistry
3          2        Physics321            Physics
2          1        Chemistry101         Chemistry


 function executionStartsHere() { 
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Course Planner');
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   panel.setId("main-panel");


   //grades
   panel.add(_getLabel("Grades"));
   uniqueGrades = _findUniqueGrades();
   gradeListBox = _getListBox(app,uniqueGrades,"grade-listbox","grades");
   var gradeHandler = app.createServerHandler('_clickGrade');
   gradeListBox.addChangeHandler(gradeHandler);
   panel.add(gradeListBox);

   //courses
   panel.add(_getLabel("Courses"));
   courseListBox = _getListBox(app,{},"course-listbox","courses");
   var courseHandler = app.createServerHandler('_clickCourse');
   courseListBox.addChangeHandler(courseHandler);
   panel.add(courseListBox);

   //semester
   panel.add(_getLabel("Semester"));
   semesterListBox = _getListBox(app,{},"semester-listbox","semesters");
   panel.add(semesterListBox);


   h = app.createHidden("selectedGrade").setId("selectedGrade");
   h.setValue("1");
   panel.add(h);

   //finally
   app.add(panel);
   doc.show(app);  
 }


 function _clickGrade(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   // get value of ListBox based on name
   var selectedGrade = eventInfo.parameter.grades;
   Logger.log("In clickGrade, selected:"+selectedGrade);
   //eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade=selectedGrade;
   app.getElementById("selectedGrade").setValue(selectedGrade);
   Logger.log("eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade: "+eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade);
    _displayCourses(selectedGrade);
   return app;
 }

 function _clickCourse(eventInfo) {
   //WE NEED TO SOMEHOW PASS THE SELCTED GRADE IN HERE

   var app    = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var grade  = app.getElementById("selectedGrade")
   var grade2 = eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade;
   var course = eventInfo.parameter.courses;
    Logger.log("Selected grade, grade2, course: "+grade+" ,"+grade2+" ,"+course);
   _displaySemesters(grade,course);
   return app;
 }

 function _displayCourses(grade) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   validCourses = _findValidCourses(grade);
   lb = app.getElementById("course-listbox");
   _populateListBox(lb,validCourses);
 }

 function _displaySemesters(grade,course){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   validSemesters = _findValidSemesters(grade,course);
   lb = app.getElementById("semester-listbox");
   _populateListBox(lb,validSemesters);
 }


 function _findUniqueGrades(){
   var workBook = _getWorkBook(); 
   var sheet = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
   var graderows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1); 

   var grades= {}; 
   for(var i=1; i<graderows.length; i++) { //skip the first row (labels)
     if(graderows[i] != "" && graderows[i] != undefined ) {
       grades[graderows[i]]=graderows[i];
     }
   }
   return grades;
 }

 function _findValidCourses(grade) {
  var workBook = _getWorkBook();
  var sheet = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
  var graderows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1); 
  var courserows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 3);

  // loop over courserows
  //  if the grade for this courserow matches the grade we are searching for
  //     then store this courserow in an associative array
  validCourses = {};
  for(var i=0; i< courserows.length; i++) {
    if ( graderows[i] == grade ) {
      validCourses[courserows[i]] = courserows[i];
    }
  }
  return validCourses;
 } 

 function _findValidSemesters(grade,course){
  var workBook     = _getWorkBook();
  var sheet        = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
  var graderows    = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1);
  var courserows   = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 3);
  var semesterrows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 2); 

   validSemesters = {};
   for(var i=0; i< semesterrows.length; i++){
     if ( courserows[i] == course && graderows[i] == grade ){
       validSemesters[semesterrows[i]] = semesterrows[i];
     }
   }
   return validSemesters;
 }

 function _getListBox(app,items,id,label){
   var lb = app.createListBox().setId(id).setName(label);
   lb.setVisibleItemCount(1);
   //add items, if any
   for each ( i in items) {
     lb.addItem(i);
   }
   return lb;
 } 

 function _populateListBox(listBox,items){
   listBox.clear();
   Logger.log("ListBox ID: "+ listBox.getId());
   for each ( i in items) {
     Logger.log("adding item: " + i);
     listBox.addItem(i);
   }
 }

 function _getWorkBook(){
   return SpreadsheetApp.openById(employee_SPREADSHEET);
 }

 function _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook){
   return workBook.getSheets()[0];
 }

 function _getLabel(string){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   return app.createLabel(string); 
 }

 function getColumnAsArray(sheet,column) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,column,99,1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  //Logger.log("column values: " + data);

  return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you simply forgot to set a Name to your hidden widget , you only gave an ID... and as you obviously know the event parameter uses the widgets name to get back its value. :-)

```
h = app.createHidden("selectedGrade").setId("selectedGrade").setName("selectedGrade");
```

---

**EDIT :**

Oooops, you're right, I didn't notice at first.

After playing a bit with your code I found that you where forgeting a callBackElement with your handler, I also added a second hidden widget to hold the course value.
Here is a copy of your code in which I replaced the hidden widgets by textBoxes to see what was happening.
It seems to work as expected, you can hide the textBoxes when everything is ok or replace them by hidden widgets again.

```
 function executionStartsHere() { 
   var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var app = UiApp.createApplication().setTitle('Course Planner');
   var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
   panel.setId("main-panel");


   //grades
   panel.add(_getLabel("Grades"));
   uniqueGrades = _findUniqueGrades();
   gradeListBox = _getListBox(app,uniqueGrades,"grade-listbox","grades");
   var gradeHandler = app.createServerHandler('_clickGrade').addCallbackElement(panel);
   gradeListBox.addChangeHandler(gradeHandler);
   panel.add(gradeListBox);

   //courses
   panel.add(_getLabel("Courses"));
   courseListBox = _getListBox(app,{item:'First choose a grade value'},"course-listbox","courses");
   var courseHandler = app.createServerHandler('_clickCourse').addCallbackElement(panel);
   courseListBox.addChangeHandler(courseHandler);
   panel.add(courseListBox);

   //semester
   panel.add(_getLabel("Semester"));
   semesterListBox = _getListBox(app,{item:'First choose a course value'},"semester-listbox","semesters");
   panel.add(semesterListBox);


   var h = app.createTextBox().setName("selectedGrade").setId("selectedGrade");
   var h2 = app.createTextBox().setName("selectedCourse").setId("selectedCourse");
   panel.add(h).add(h2);

   //finally
   app.add(panel);
   doc.show(app);  
 }


 function _clickGrade(eventInfo) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   // get value of ListBox based on name
   var selectedGrade = eventInfo.parameter.grades;
   Logger.log("In clickGrade, selected:"+selectedGrade);
   //eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade=selectedGrade;
   app.getElementById("selectedGrade").setValue(selectedGrade);
   Logger.log("eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade: "+eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade);
    _displayCourses(selectedGrade);
   return app;
 }

 function _clickCourse(eventInfo) {
   //WE NEED TO SOMEHOW PASS THE SELCTED GRADE IN HERE

   var app    = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var grade  = app.getElementById("selectedGrade")
   var grade2 = eventInfo.parameter.selectedGrade;
   var course = eventInfo.parameter.courses;
   app.getElementById("selectedCourse").setValue(course);
    Logger.log("Selected grade, grade2, course: "+grade+" ,"+grade2+" ,"+course);
   _displaySemesters(grade2,course);
   return app;
 }

 function _displayCourses(grade) {
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   validCourses = _findValidCourses(grade);
   lb = app.getElementById("course-listbox");
   _populateListBox(lb,validCourses);
 }

 function _displaySemesters(grade,course){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   Logger.log(grade+' '+course)
   validSemesters = _findValidSemesters(grade,course);
   lb = app.getElementById("semester-listbox");
   _populateListBox(lb,validSemesters);
 }


 function _findUniqueGrades(){
   var workBook = _getWorkBook(); 
   var sheet = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
   var graderows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1); 

   var grades= {}; 
   for(var i=1; i<graderows.length; i++) { //skip the first row (labels)
     if(graderows[i] != "" && graderows[i] != undefined ) {
       grades[graderows[i]]=graderows[i];
     }
   }
   return grades;
 }

 function _findValidCourses(grade) {
  var workBook = _getWorkBook();
  var sheet = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
  var graderows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1); 
  var courserows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 3);

  // loop over courserows
  //  if the grade for this courserow matches the grade we are searching for
  //     then store this courserow in an associative array
  validCourses = {};
  for(var i=0; i< courserows.length; i++) {
    if ( graderows[i] == grade ) {
      validCourses[courserows[i]] = courserows[i];
    }
  }
  return validCourses;
 } 

 function _findValidSemesters(grade,course){
  var workBook     = _getWorkBook();
  var sheet        = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
  var graderows    = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1);
  var courserows   = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 3);
  var semesterrows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 2); 

   validSemesters = {};
   for(var i=0; i< semesterrows.length; i++){
     if ( courserows[i] == course && graderows[i] == grade ){
       validSemesters[semesterrows[i]] = semesterrows[i];
     }
   }
   return validSemesters;
 }

 function _getListBox(app,items,id,label){
   var lb = app.createListBox().setId(id).setName(label);
   lb.setVisibleItemCount(1);
   //add items, if any
   for each ( i in items) {
     lb.addItem(i);
   }
   return lb;
 } 

 function _populateListBox(listBox,items){
   listBox.clear();
   Logger.log("ListBox ID: "+ listBox.getId());
   for each ( i in items) {
     Logger.log("adding item: " + i);
     listBox.addItem(i);
   }
 }

 function _getWorkBook(){
   return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
 }

 function _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook){
   return workBook.getSheets()[0];
 }

 function _getLabel(string){
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   return app.createLabel(string); 
 }

 function getColumnAsArray(sheet,column) {
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(1,column,99,1);
  var data = dataRange.getValues()
  //Logger.log("column values: " + data);

  return data;
 }
```

Comment: Serge, thanks for your feedback. I changed to code to what you suggested, I set the value in _clickGrade but I am still getting back undefined inside _clickCourse. In addition I think calling createHidden with a string option as I did originally was setting the name. As mentioned, I added an explicit call to setName, and it's still not working. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is that when I set the parameter in _clickGrade, somehow the parameter is not getting saved properly back to the app. I say this because when I am in _clickCourse, the parameter has a value of 'undefined'. Should I be doing something else in _clickGrade to tell the app the value has been reset?

Comment: Another comment : when you use _displaySemesters(grade,course); , grade is a widget, not a value... that's why I replaced by _displaySemesters(grade2,course);, grade2 being the widget's value we get with the eventInfo parameter.

Comment: Serge, thanks a lot for your help! I appreciate your quick responses! Can I ask an addendum question? Right now the call backs are triggered only onValueChange in the listbox. This means that if the first value displayed in courses is what the user wants, the user will not see the correct Semester. The user will have to select the wrong semester, then reselect the first semester. I am guessing I need to register my functions with an additional callback, any thoughts on what that should be? Thanks!

Comment: A possible way to avoid this situation would be to show a first item in the grade listBox that invites people to choose a grade... I tested it like that : `function _findUniqueGrades(){
   var workBook = _getWorkBook(); 
   var sheet = _getLearningOutcomeSheet(workBook);
   var graderows = getColumnAsArray(sheet, 1); 

   var grades= {item:'Make a choice'}; 
   for(var i=1; i<graderows.length; i++) { //skip the first row (labels)
     if(graderows[i] != "" && graderows[i] != undefined ) {
       grades[graderows[i]]=graderows[i];
     }
   }
   return grades;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

use setTag() and getTag() to pass values in these circs. The tag value is then passed to your handler in the eventinfo parameters.